Duplicate key in mongodb, how to fix?
So I am trying to deploy a website and there is a products page, i have made the models and routes but when i try to post a product for the second time, it says this
E11000 duplicate key error collection
here is my product model and route
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: '',
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: '',
    },
    cookingInstruction: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    quantityInStock: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    id: false,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }, // Include virtual properties when converting to JSON
  }
);

// Define the virtual property 'isActive'
productSchema.virtual('isActive').get(function () {
  return this.quantityInStock > 0; // 'isActive' is true if quantityInStock is greater than 0
});

// Create the Product model based on the schema
export const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

`your text`
router.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { name } = request.body;

    // Check if a product with the same name already exists
    const existingProduct = await Product.findOne({ name });

    if (existingProduct) {
      return response.status(400).send({ message: 'Product with this name already exists' });
    }

    const newProduct = {
      name: request.body.name,
      description: request.body.description,
      price: request.body.price,
      category: request.body.category,
    };

    const product = await Product.create(newProduct);

    return response.status(201).send(product);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});


I tried to add an id inside the model but it keeps saying that error.

Does this answer your question? E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose This question has a lot of scenarios covered.

Can you please execute the following command in a MongoShell instance, it would list all indexes in the collection,  please analyse it and confirm all indexes listed are still required for the app. If some index found not relevant, please remove it and try your code -  db.products.getIndexes()

The E11000 error should tell you both which field has a duplicate value, and what the duplicate value is.
